# Different layers styles according to a variable

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3, geojson

I want to show few maps on the page, basically they are all the same, except that they have different layers that differ according to a parameter value.

The code I wrote is showing the layers on all the maps, but the style is always taking the last value of the variable in the loop. In my case always taking the value of 2.

I want to know where is exactly my mistake that the styling of the layer is not being according to the loop value.

The part of my script that I wrote is as following

```
for (variable  = 0 ; variable <= 2 ; variable++){
  vectorLayers[variable] = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
      url: '/myLocation/myFiles',
      format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
    }),
    style:  function(feature) {
      id = feature.get('reading'+variable);
      parameter = id[1];
      fill.setColor(
        parameter >= 0 && paramter < 0.10 ? lightBlue:
        ...);
        return style;
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The style function will not be executed in the for loop as you are expecting. The for loop will first create all the layers then style function will be called for each feature of each layer. Thats why variable value will be 2 always.
 Debug carefully you will see.

Edit 1 :
Write a method which will create Vector layer and call it inside the loop and pass the variable value so that the value will be maintained correctly.

```
for (variable  = 0 ; variable <= 2 ; variable++){
  vectorLayers[variable] = createVectorLayer(variable);
}

function createVectorLayer(variable) {
    var layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
      url: '/myLocation/myFiles',
      format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
    }),
    style:  function(feature) {
      id = feature.get('reading'+variable);
      parameter = id[1];
      fill.setColor(
        parameter >= 0 && paramter < 0.10 ? lightBlue:
        ...);
        return style;
      }
    });
    return layer;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I noticed this by trying to make 3 different function, each of them return style then called them through the loop. That's the only way it worked. But I wanted to avoid creating too many functions. I don't think it's practical. 
Do you have any idea to solve this?

Comment: I have edited my answer to include the working code.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your code edit helped me solve the problem and get what I wanted.